# How to best modify a group of member objects the same way?

Tags: c++, object

Maybe I'm being to picky, but I would like to have your opinion on how to best code something like this (my problem is much more complicated but it can be simplified like this):

```
class A
{
public:
        A ();
        A (const size_t dim0, const size_t dim1);

        void set_is_x_allocated (const bool);
        void set_is_y_allocated (const bool);
        void set_is_z_allocated (const bool);

private:
        void allocate (vector<vector<double>> &) const; ??

        size_t dim0;
        size_t dim1;

        bool is_x_allocated;
        bool is_y_allocated;
        bool is_z_allocated;

        vector<vector<double>> x;
        vector<vector<double>> y;
        vector<vector<double>> z;
};
```

When the dimensions are given, I would like to allocate x, y, z the same way (depending on how the booleans is_x/y/z_allocated are set). The solutions I have are those at the moment:

Solution 1: Create an allocate function like above, and call `if (is_x_allocated) allocate (x);` etc.

Pros: x, y, z will be allocated the same way -> easier to spot errors, to modify the code if a third dimension comes in in the future.

Cons: as allocate can be used for any other `vector<vector<double>>`, should it be `const` or not?

Solution 2: Create an allocate_x (), allocate_y (), allocate_z (), call `if (is_x_allocated) allocate_x();`

Pros: It's adapted to the situation and allocate_x/y/z are definitely non-constant.

Cons: I have to copy the allocation code 3 times. I might make some mistakes + the code will be more complicated to modify if a 3rd dimension comes in for example.

How would you code this in an effective way? Maybe a lambda function inside a `void allocate ()` function, but I feel like this would be making a too big deal of what it really is...

Comment: `std::array<vector<vector<double>>, 3> m_xyz;` + cycle or by index

Comment: What do you mean by allocate ? Allocate memory as in `new` and `delete` ? Or push data into the vector ?

Comment: It's like `new` and `delete`, more precisely `resize` with dim0 and dim1 for vectors/valarrays. We have very big data, that's why we want to allocate only one table if we need one, instead of all three.

Comment: What is the wrong with using solution 1? It doesn't seem like a contra point at all, that you are not sure wether or not to use const.